# Matlab: C++ header file for dll

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, header-files, loadlibrary

I have a very simple header file for a dll library but it is in C++. Anyone can help me to edit it in a way to be compatible with "LoadLibrary" command in Matlab (native C)? I realize it is not a general problem but more likely lack of my knowledge. But if the solution is simple, I would appreciate any advice.

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the TRACKERERRORSDLL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. this symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// TRACKERERRORSDLL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef TRACKERERRORSDLL_EXPORTS
#define TRACKERERRORSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#define TRACKERERRORSDLL_VB __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
#else
#define TRACKERERRORSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#define TRACKERERRORSDLL_VB __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall
#endif

#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool TRACKERERRORSDLL_API GetTPIErrorDescription_wstring(long errorNumber, 
                                                 basic_string<__wchar_t> & shortDescription,
                                                 basic_string<__wchar_t> & longDescription,
                                                 basic_string<__wchar_t> & solutionDescription,
                                                 bool & isAutoRecoverOnGreenState);

bool TRACKERERRORSDLL_API GetTPIErrorDescription_wstring(long errorNumber, 
                                                 basic_string<unsigned short> & shortDescription,
                                                 basic_string<unsigned short> & longDescription,
                                                 basic_string<unsigned short> & solutionDescription,
                                                 bool & isAutoRecoverOnGreenState);

bool TRACKERERRORSDLL_API GetTPIErrorDescription_string(long errorNumber, 
                                                 string & shortDescription,
                                                 string & longDescription,
                                                 string & solutionDescription,
                                                 bool & isAutoRecoverOnGreenState);

bool TRACKERERRORSDLL_API GetTPIErrorDescription_CString(long errorNumber, 
                                                 CString & shortDescription,
                                                 CString & longDescription,
                                                 CString & solutionDescription,
                                                 bool & isAutoRecoverOnGreenState);

bool TRACKERERRORSDLL_VB GetTPIErrorDescription_VB(int errorNumber, 
                                                 LPSTR* shortDescription,
                                                 LPSTR* longDescription,
                                                 LPSTR* solutionDescription,
                                                 bool* isAutoRecoverOnGreenState);
```

Link to download the library (64bit):
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzzppV2CG8ZldzFRVzJUa252MHc/edit?usp=sharing

Matlab R2013a 64bit

Comment: Have you found [this thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154975) yet?

Comment: you could also create a C++ MEX-function that links against the above library. Then its easy to use the version `GetTPIErrorDescription_string` which takes `std::string` and return those to MATLAB as `mxArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only function that you can call is `GetTPIErrorDescription_VB`. All the others use C++ classes that you cannot access. So I suggest that you do the following:

1. Remove all the other functions from the header file.
2. Remove the `#include` and the `using` lines.
3. Remove the `#ifdef` and replace `TRACKERERRORSDLL_VB` with `__stdcall`.
4. Either include `windows.h` or add some `#define` statements for the Win32 types.
5. Possibly deal with the `bool` type depending on whether or not MATLAB knows how to deal with it. If MATLAB won't recognise it, replace `bool` with `int`.

At that point the call to `loadlibrary` should work and then you just need to write the code that calls `calllib`.

The resulting header file might look like something this:

```
#define LPSTR char*

__declspec(dllimport) bool __stdcall GetTPIErrorDescription_VB(
    int errorNumber, 
    LPSTR* shortDescription,
    LPSTR* longDescription,
    LPSTR* solutionDescription,
    bool* isAutoRecoverOnGreenState
);
```

Finally, do note that `LPSTR*` is a rather surprising type to encounter. It suggests that the DLL is going to allocate `char*` C strings, and then return them to you through the three description parameters. This presents a memory allocation issue. Who is going to deallocate the memory? Does it even need to be deallocated, or is it static? Those issues will need to be resolved by consulting the documentation for the DLL.

Comment: Superb! I will try that and let you know. Is there also a possibility to use a mex file? Unfortunately no further documentation of dll is available for customers. Do you think it may cause serious problems in the form as it is?

Comment: @flogs You'll need to make some guesses in order to call that function. It's not enough to know the parameter types, you also need to know the semantics. A mex file would be another good choice. You'd still need to use `GetTPIErrorDescription_VB` unless you could guarantee to dynamically link to the same CRT as the DLL. And does the DLL even link to the CRT?

Comment: "loadlibrary" now reports no errors. But as you said, I have a trouble calling "GetTPIErrorDescription_VB" with "calllib". It says there is no such method. I am not sure how can I make guesses. There is also associated .lib file. Can it be useful somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you need the `__declspec(dllimport)`. Looking at the calllib that I used once upon a time, my header includes that.

Comment: Ok, I´ll try. Can I have one more question? (I dont want to start a new thread) How can I listen to events in my GUI application when it is inactive (no button has been pressed at the moment and no computation is running but still I want to listen to instrument´s messages)?

Comment: I don't know. That seems unrelated to this topic.